# what is the exact value of $\operatorname e$

Tags: calculus

how the value of "$\operatorname e$" is derived but I know here
$$ \operatorname e^x= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} $$
putting $ x=1 $ we get $$ \operatorname e = 1 +1+ \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{6}+ \cdots$$
so my question is how the expression for $\operatorname e^x $ is derived

Comment: Do you know what Taylor series are?

Comment: How do you define $e$?  For many people, that can be considered the *definition.* (And, thus, doesn't need any derivation)

Comment: Definitions of $e$ are abundant. Asking "how the expression for $e^x$ is derived" is a bit like asking "who came first, egg or chicken". Some people take the series as a definition for $e^x$. Do you have a definition in mind?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)

Comment: I suppose you prefer that $e$ is defined by $e = 1 + 1 + 1/2! + 1/3! + \cdots$ and then ask how to derive $e^{x} = f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}(x^{n})/n!$. This is a simple exercise of series multiplication provided that $x $ is rational. We need to show that $f(x + y) = f(x)f(y)$ for all real $x, y$ and this leads to $f(x) = \{f(1)\}^{x} = e^{x}$ for rational $x$. To extend for irrational $x$ you need to define the irrational power/exponent $e^{x}$ somehow. One simple way out is to let this series be the definition of $e^{x}$ when $x$ is irrational.

Comment: Perhaps [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function) might prove helpful.